# iTextSharp: Clipping path lost after RestoreState

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I am using iTextSharp to generate PDF files.  I've run into a problem where if I `SaveState()` then `RestoreState()` after doing `Clip()`, then my clipping path is lost and further drawing is not clipped.

I don't know if it's a bug in iText/iTextSharp, or if I am doing something incorrect.  Below is sample c# code.

```cs
using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(@"Problem.PDF"))
{
    var doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document();
    var writer = iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fileStream);

    doc.Open();

    var content = writer.DirectContent;

    // Stroke where the blue box will be drawn
    content.NewPath();
    content.MoveTo(250, 250);
    content.LineTo(250, 350);
    content.LineTo(350, 350);
    content.LineTo(350, 250);
    content.LineTo(250, 250);
    content.SetRGBColorStroke(0, 0, 255);
    content.Stroke();

    // Stroke where the red box will be drawn
    content.NewPath();
    content.MoveTo(250, 150);
    content.LineTo(250, 250);
    content.LineTo(350, 250);
    content.LineTo(350, 150);
    content.LineTo(250, 150);
    content.SetRGBColorStroke(255, 0, 0);
    content.Stroke();

    // Set the clipping box
    content.NewPath();
    content.MoveTo(200, 200);
    content.LineTo(200, 300);
    content.LineTo(300, 300);
    content.LineTo(300, 200);
    content.LineTo(200, 200);
    content.Clip();

    // Save state, then fill the blue box (will be clipped)
    content.SaveState();

    content.NewPath();
    content.MoveTo(250, 250);
    content.LineTo(250, 350);
    content.LineTo(350, 350);
    content.LineTo(350, 250);
    content.LineTo(250, 250);
    content.SetRGBColorFill(0, 0, 255);
    content.Fill();

    // Restore state
    content.RestoreState();

    // Save state again, then fill the red box (will not be clipped... why not?)
    content.SaveState();

    content.NewPath();
    content.MoveTo(250, 150);
    content.LineTo(250, 250);
    content.LineTo(350, 250);
    content.LineTo(350, 150);
    content.LineTo(250, 150);
    content.SetRGBColorFill(255, 0, 0);
    content.Fill();

    content.RestoreState();

    doc.Close();
}
```

In the above code, I am stroking a red box and blue box to indicate where the clipped boxes will be drawn (for verification).  Those stroked boxes should not be clipped.  The filled blue box is correctly clipped.  **The red filled box is not clipped, but it should be to my understanding.**

I have added `ClosePath()` to various paths (clipping, filling, stroking, etc.) without any changes to the results.

I require to do the `SaveState()/RestoreState()` after the `Clip()` due to setting of various gstate values (opacity, blend mode, etc.)

I have tested using iTextSharp 5.5.3 and the LGPL version 4.1.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are thinking that `NewPath()` means "I would like to start drawing a new path, here are my coordinates". Instead, it more means "I'm done drawing my path, any further operators should start a new path. Or from the spec:

> End the path object without filling or stroking it. This operator
>   shall be a path-painting no-op, used primarily for the side effect of
>   changing the current clipping path (see 8.5.4, "Clipping Path
>   Operators").

You can pretty much get rid of all of your `NewPath()` calls except the one that's most needed and that's directly after called `Clip()`

```
content.Clip();
content.NewPath();
```

Comment: Glad that worked, I had to read the spec 10 times before it finally clicked what it was saying. Luckily I wasn't used to seeing the `NewPath()` command before so that at least gave me a hint!

Comment: I'm used to EPS syntax where `NewPath` is used to start a new path.  Performing a stroke or fill does not reset the current path, so you can fill, stroke, clip the same path without needing to restart or redefine the path.

Comment: That's actually kind of funny because it actually specifically talks about how the PDFs spec in this regard is different than the PS spec (which I assume EPS is based off of). "In PDF (unlike PostScript), the current path is not part of the graphics state and is not saved and restored". So it sounds like they knew they were doing something weird!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a bug in iText, nor in iTextSharp of any version. You're writing the PDF syntax operator after operator almost manually.

Let's take a look at ISO-32000-1, section 8.5.4, entitled "Clipping path operators", more specifically in NOTE 2. I quote:

> since the clipping path is part of the graphics state, its effect can
>   be localized to specific graphics objects by enclosing the
>   modification of the clipping path and the painting of those objects
>   between a pair of `q` and `Q` operators (see 8.4.2, "Graphics State
>   Stack"). Execution of the `Q` operator causes the clipping path to
>   revert to the value that was saved by the `q` operator before the
>   clipping path was modified.

In case you wonder what the `q` and `Q` operators are in the above definition: `q` is the *save state* operator, `Q` is the *restore state* operator.

I must admit something odd is happening. One would expect the clipping path still to be active after the first `RestoreState()`. If this syntax isn't rendered correctly, then the viewer rendering the syntax may be doing something wrong by discarding the clipping path...